# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError al tratar de ordenar un ArrayList

Tags: java, excepciones, ordenamiento, out-of-memory-error, complejidad

Buen día, estoy desarrollando un programa para ayudarme a contabilizar que tanto demoran los ordenamientos básicos y así hacer un análisis de complejidad, pero me tope con este error

> java.land.OutOfMemoryError : GC overhead limit exceeded

no se si tenga que ver con mi pc o algo mas.

Agradezco mucho la ayuda y respuesta.

Este es el código main que en el que corro los ordenamientos, los algoritmos de ordenamiento son los mismos pero desarrollados en una clase aparte y llamados con el método sort().

```
public class main {

    static ArrayList <Integer> listaNumeros = new ArrayList<>();


    public static void leerDatos(){


        File archivo = new File("10_7");
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(archivo);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String numeros ;
            while((numeros = br.readLine())!=null) { 

                String []lista = numeros.split(",");
                for(int k = 0;  k < lista.length; k++){
                    int datos = Integer.parseInt(lista[k]);
                    listaNumeros.add(datos); 


                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*
            Sort1.  Ordenamiento Burbuja.
            Sort2.  Ordenamiento por Selección.
            Sort3.  Ordenamiento por Inserción.
            Sort4.  Shellsort.
            Sort5.  Quicksort.
            Sort6.  Treesort.
            Sort7.  Heapsort.
        */
        int key=1; /////////////////////////////////////CAMBIAR EL NUMERO SEGUN EL SORT QUE SE VA A HACER
        double tiempo; //Se medira el tiempo
        leerDatos(); //Lee el archivo para 


        BubbleSort Sort1 = new BubbleSort();
        SelectionSort Sort2 = new SelectionSort();
        Insercion Sort3 = new Insercion();
        Shell Sort4 = new Shell();
        QuickSort Sort5 = new QuickSort();
        Treesort Sort6 = new Treesort();
        HeapSort Sort7 = new HeapSort();
        long start = System.nanoTime();//inicia a contabilizar el tiempo
        long end ;// fin de contabilizar metodo

            Sort1.Sort(listaNumeros);
            end = System.nanoTime();// fin de contabilizar metodo
            tiempo= (double)(end-start)*1.0e-9;
            System.out.println("\nTiempo total "+ tiempo);  

            start = System.nanoTime();
            Sort2.Sort(listaNumeros);
            end = System.nanoTime();// fin de contabilizar metodo
            tiempo= (double)(end-start)*1.0e-9;
            System.out.println("\nTiempo total "+ tiempo);  

            start = System.nanoTime();
            Sort3.sort(listaNumeros);
            end = System.nanoTime();// fin de contabilizar metodo
            tiempo= (double)(end-start)*1.0e-9;
            System.out.println("\nTiempo total "+ tiempo);  

            start = System.nanoTime();
            Sort4.shell_Method(listaNumeros);
            end = System.nanoTime();// fin de contabilizar metodo
            tiempo= (double)(end-start)*1.0e-9;
            System.out.println("\nTiempo total "+ tiempo);  

            start = System.nanoTime();
            Sort5.quickSort(listaNumeros, 0, listaNumeros.size()-1);
            end = System.nanoTime();// fin de contabilizar metodo
            tiempo= (double)(end-start)*1.0e-9;
            System.out.println("\nTiempo total "+ tiempo);  

            start = System.nanoTime();
            Sort6.agregarListas(listaNumeros);
            end = System.nanoTime();// fin de contabilizar metodo
            tiempo= (double)(end-start)*1.0e-9;
            System.out.println("\nTiempo total "+ tiempo);  

            start = System.nanoTime();
            Sort7.ordenar(listaNumeros);
            end = System.nanoTime();// fin de contabilizar metodo


        //for (int i = 0; i < listaNumeros.size(); i++) System.out.println(listaNumeros.get(i));

        tiempo= (double)(end-start)*1.0e-9;
        System.out.println("\nTiempo total "+ tiempo);  
    }


}
```

Muchas gracias por la atención

Comment: Si ejecuta metodo por metodo sucede lo mismo?,

Comment: No, individualmente no genera este error, pero estoy buscando una forma de correrlos todos sin que haya inconvenientes notando que es un archivo bastante pesado ya que es de 10^7 como se puede ver aca.

File archivo = new File("10_7");

la linea en la que leo el archivo. Pero no se en donde resalta el problema que me genera dentro del código o si es de recursos por mi pc.

Comment: Mira estos enlaces, http://www.josevazquez.net/definicion-de-java-heap-y-java-heap-dump/ y https://community.alfresco.com/thread/200627-javalangoutofmemoryerror-java-heap-space el primero explica el comportamiento de la memoria en java, el segundo es un error similar y como fue solucionado. Espero te guien.

Comment: Vale gracias, leeré lo que mandaste y lo tendré en cuenta en la nueva versión a ver si logra tener solución, muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Cuántos números hay en el archivo? ¿Cuánto de memoria dedicas a tu aplicación al ejecutarse? Quizás con aumentar la RAM mediante `-Xmx` puedas resolver el problema.

Comment: En el archivo hay una lista de tamaño 10^7 de números aleatorios desordenados separados por ','.
me podrías explicar mejor lo de que tanda memoria le dedico a la aplicación? yo solo procuro leer el archivo y guardarlo todo en un ArrayList.

Comment: Por lo visto tu problema es que hay muchos números en tu archivo, por lo que la memoria que usas en la aplicación es insuficiente. Necesitarás más de 70 GBs de ram si quieres tener toda la información del archivo en memoria. Luce más como un ejercicio para ordenar la información haciendo un mejor uso de los recursos del equipo.

Comment: Fuera de eso, el benchmark que haces tiene serios problemas. No obtendrás los resultados esperados para evaluar cuál de los métodos de ordenamiento es el más rápido.

Comment: si lo que necesitas es manejar tiempos te recomiendo implementar hilos para que no llenes la memoria con números en coma flotante exorbitantes.